# HV Pulse Blocking with Common Mode Choke

Tags: high-voltage, isolation, pulse, ferrite, common-mode-choke

I need to apply a reset current to a magnetic core on the same circuit as a ~25kV 30ns long pulse.  I know there are a number of ways to do this, but for simplicity sake I would like to protect my current supply with a common mode choke.
This is sort of what I'm thinking so far for this circuit, but the parameters of the choke are sort of elusive for a pulse rather than some harmonic noise.
[image: Core Reset Circuit]
Will a circuit like this be adequate to protect my voltage supply? Are there other factors that need to be considered?

Here is an example of the pulse that needs to be blocked (voltage axis not to scale):
[image: Peak at 25kV]

Answer (score 2):

Lets assume each side of that choke has 1pF parasitic capacitance across the windings.

Lets assume the dV/dT of the pulse is 25,000 volts in 15 nanoseconds.

What is the current thru the 1pF?

I = C * dV/dT = 1e-12 * 25,000 / 15 e-9 = 1e-12+9 * 25,000/15 = 1.67 amps.

Can your "protected" side survive with 1.67 amps arriving, during that pulse?